# Check if i in a loop has the same value integers in an array

Tags: arrays, for-loop, integer

I have a usual for-loop:

```
for (var i : int = 0; int < someArray.length; i++)
```

I have also an array with different integers (lets call it integer-array), for example 5, 9, 14, 19, 23, 28, ... or so. I now want to check inside of my for-loop if i has the same value of any of those integers in the integer-array. How could I achieve that? Thank you!

Comment: Knowing the language would be appreciated. For example, in c# you could take advantage of methods like `Contains` while in basic you would have to loop through and check.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to do that is with nested loops.  Like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<intArray.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<intArray.length; j++){
        if(intArray[j] == i){
            System.out.println(i + " is in the array");
        }
    }
}
```

It's not very efficient, but it should do what you need.

Comment: You can add a break if the array is sorted and j is larger then i. :)

Comment: You could also add a break for the inside on a Boolean variable found which is false at the top of the first for loop and true if found. Something like j < intArray.length && !found;